# C# configuration.SetBasePath

Tags: c#, configuration

I can change the base path for the configuration with:

```cs
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
  .UseWindowsService()
  .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configuration) =>
    {
       configuration.Sources.Clear();
       configuration.SetBasePath(Application.StartupPath);
       configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
    })
  .ConfigureLogging(logging => { logging.ClearProviders(); })
```

What is the default base path of the configuration? How is it set? In the previous example, I used Application.StartupPath, but which commands are used in the background? What is the default path when I use the following code:

```cs
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
  .UseWindowsService()
  .ConfigureLogging(logging => { logging.ClearProviders(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like method GetFileProvider on class FileConfigurationExtensions is used. It uses AppContext.BaseDirectory. Which calls GetBaseDirectoryCore. There uses Environment.ProcessPath or Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location